# Visibility/Height Requirements for Plumbing Air-Gaps (Commercial Building)

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Are there any visibility/height requirements with regards to plumbing air-gap design/installation?

We're looking at using an air gap device to allow HVAC condensate drip to enter a buildings drainage system.  I've seen this before on residential applications where the washing machine drain and HVAC condensate drip are combined into a single box using a product such as:

http://www.siouxchief.com/products/supply/access/laundry-boxes/oxbox-washing-machine-outlet-box?template=P3Technical

or

https://www.ferguson.com/product/lancaster-pump-34-x-1-12-in-fip-x-mip-multipurpose-air-gap-lg175/_/R-4376003?skuId=4376003

or

https://www.freshwatersystems.com/p-328-mr-drain-air-gap-md-10a-15-or-2-standpipes.aspx

Customer is requesting that air-gap boxes be located below counter level with cutouts in the back of the installed cabinets.  Condensate from units on second floor too low for air gap to be installed in second flow.

Here's the concern behind my question.  What happens if there is a system backup due to a clog and my air-gap is the lowest point?  Obviously it would result in an overflow.  If the air-gap is visible this would result in simple cleanup.  If the air-gap is hidden behind cabinets or in a wall then the overflow would go unnoticed for a period of time and result in a much larger (expensive) cleanup.

Seems like there should be code requirements that prevent hidden air-gaps or require them to be located above a nearby sink or other drain that is visible so that an overflow is "contained" in a visible area.

Thanks.